# Gem Installs not executing after update system-wide update Arch Linux

Tags: linux, bash, arch-linux, ruby

When trying to execute `sass --watch scss:css` inside of a target folder I get returned the message `command not found`

I know I had sass installed. `gem list` doesn't show that it's installed anymore.

I run `sudo gem install sass` and get the following message:

```
WARNING: You don't have /root/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin in your PATH
         gem executables will not run.
```

I go to my `.bashrc` file. I have `PATH="$(ruby -e 'print Gem.user_dir')/bin:$PATH"`

I also put it in `/etc/bash.bashrc` just in case. Nothing Changes.

I go to /etc/profile and insert:

```
#Setting the GEM_PATH and GEM_HOME variables may not be necessary, check 'gem env' output to verify whether both variables already exist 
 GEM_HOME=$(ls -t -U | ruby -e 'puts Gem.user_dir')
 GEM_PATH=$GEM_HOME
 export PATH=$PATH:$GEM_HOME/bin
```

I reload profile with `. /etc/profile`

I try reinstalling sass with `sudo gem install sass`

Still the same error message. `gem list` still doesn't show `sass`

What now??

Comment: Did you add the PATH directory to root's bashrc or to that of a non-privileged user?

Comment: I indeed did not have a .bashrc inside /root/ I copied the file from /home/USER and retried the install. Same error message.

Comment: sorry, but I do not understand whether you are trying  to execute the command as toor or as an unprivileged user.

Comment: I entered the directory path manually into /root/.bashrc and it works now. Although that's probably not the ideal solution. How can I edit ruby Gem.user_dir ?

Comment: I'm running gem as a superuser

Comment: Why should it not be the ideal solution? It is perfectly fine.

Comment: Ideal would be changing application settings inside of application configuration files. Especially considering that a new version may change the file structure (as might have been the case here). It makes more sense for the application to change it's own settings than to go in and change .bashrc of the root user, don't ya think? Ideally.. I don't have to manage the minutae of every single application I use, so that I can focus on creating things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default in Arch Linux, when running `gem`, gems are installed per-user (into `~/.gem/ruby/`), instead of system-wide (into `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/`).

This is considered the best way to manage gems on Arch, because otherwise they might interfere with gems installed by Pacman.

Gems can be installed system wide by running the `gem` command as root, appended with the `--no-user-install` flag. This flag can be set as default by replacing `--user-install` by `--no-user-install` in `/etc/gemrc` (system-wide) or `~/.gemrc` (per-user, overrides system-wide).

Type in your terminal

```
sudo gem install sass --no-user-install
```

[See the arch wiki about ruby gems. Read Installing gems per-user or system-wide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ruby#RubyGems)

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to install the gem using sudo, but the system knows the path for your user but not for the sudo user.

To solve this, Add the following line to your `~/.bashrc` or `.~/zshrc` file:

```
PATH="$(ruby -e 'print Gem.user_dir')/bin:$PATH"
```

Use the `source` command to update your profile file or reopen your terminal.

If you use zsh:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

or with bash

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

In this way, you will install your gems without sudo, like this example:

```
gem install rspec
```